# Filter a large log file using powerscript

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter a large log file.
Is there a way to read a line from the log,
if the line contains less than 2 characters, delete the entire line from the log using power-script

I have come up with a way of counting characters in the file

```
  Get-Content ./output.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ | Measure-Object -Character } | Out-File count.txt
```

This counts each line and then outputs the characters counted into another file

And I know how to delete an empty line

```
  Get-Content .\output.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} | Set-Content out.txt
```

or a line that contains a specific character or string

```
  Get-Content .\in.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'STRING'} | Set-Content out.txt
```

Is there a way to pipe the output and ask "if the count is <=1 delete that line from the log"

Basically

```
    for each line
      if line is <= 1 delete line
      else leave alone
```

I hope this makes sense to you guys, I find it hard to get out whats in my head sometimes in a way that makes sense to others.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_ is a [string]/[System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) and a string has properties and methods of which one tells us the length of the string.

```
Get-Content .\output.txt | where {$_.Length -gt 1} | Set-Content out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Loads :)
And it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regular expression to remove lines with less than 2 characters, you can do the following:

```
Get-Content .\in.txt | ? { $_ -match '..' } | Set-Content .\out.txt
```

The expression `..` matches strings with at least 2 characters (not including newlines).

Comment: Brilliant, it worked.  Thanks loads.  I'm not sure how or why it works but I'll work it out

Comment: `Get-Content` returns the contents of the file as an array of lines. The regular expression allows all lines with 2 or more characters to pass and discards the rest.